# Evaluating $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt n$ $\log({n+3\over n})$

Tags: sequences-and-series

What test should I use to prove whether the series converges or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** use the fact that $$
\log (1+u)\sim_{u\to 0} u
$$

Comment: I used the fact that $log(1+\frac3n)\sim _{x\to \infty} \frac3n$, so the series become $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt n$ $\frac3n$. Simplifying I have $3\sum_{n=1}^\infty {1\over n^\frac12}$, which is a p-series and, since $p=\frac12<1$, it diverges. Is that correct?

Comment: the series does not **become** the other. This is just that if one converges, so does the other. Otherwise, it is correct

Comment: You're right, the series **behaves** like the other. So, by comparison, since it diverges, so does the other. Thank you!